# Enable LANMAN policy via batch file

Tags: batch

I used below script to try enabling the LANMAN-WORKSTATION but in vain.

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation /v AllowInsecureGuestAuth /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to enable "AllowInsecureGuestAuth". Did you read the text in the image which says it's a really bad idea in terms of security?

Comment: We have some operation which needs to do this.